# Asciidoctorj : How to allow extension to write additional files

Tags: asciidoctor

I'm trying to build an extension to customize look/feel/behaviour of the standard HTMLConverter via an AsciiDoctorJ extension.

The "look and feel" part consists in adding custom CSS/JS to the final document. This is achievable via the Postprocessor or DocInfoProcessor API as long as data is inlined in the HTML.

It does not seem possible the write external files to the final destination mostly because the API doesn't have access to it.

The workaround seems to write a custom converter (or extending the ruby HTMLConverter) which would be a bit overkill.

It would be nice that one of these API to be as flexible as the Syntax Highlighter API, that can link and copy external resources: https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctorj/latest/syntax-highlighting/link-external-resources/

Is there a way to achieve this with only the standard AsciidoctorJ extension API ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that one can access the output directory via document options (the `to_dir` option).
=> `document.getOptions().get("to_dir")`